# Vista Credential Provider with Newlines

Tags: c++, windows-vista

I'm trying to build a Vista Credential Provider.  I have a field whose type is CPFT_SMALL_TEXT.  I would like to put a multiline string into this field, but it keeps getting cut off part way through with an ellipsis appended at the break.  How can I avoid this and get my multiline string to show up?

Answer (score 2):

Did you think about simply creating multiple fields and feeding each of them a single line?

Answer (score 0):

Does the text break whenever a newline character should be?
Does it always break at the same length?